# Hibernate doesn't locate hibernate.cfg.xml in src folder, but it's there

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm making a Maven Java project in Intelij, with persistance using Hibernate.

In my first test of persisting an object, Hibernate acuses an error that says it's not finding hibernate.cfg.xml in src folder. But it is there, as you can see in the image bellow.

I've tried to put hibernate.cfg in the directory main/resources too, and it stills not be found.

Th topic [Hibernate ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675771/hibernate-configurationexception-could-not-locate-cfg-xml-resource-hibernate-c)
didn't helped me, because I don't know how to do what the answers describes.

Thanks for the help

[image]

Comment: `src/main/resources` **is** the correct location. Make sure you build after you fix that.

Comment: This will help you out :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349852/hibernate-cfg-xml-not-found-in-intellij